# MYSQL: Join rows as columns

Tags: mysql, join

I'm using **MySQL**, and trying to sort/join a table with multiple rows of data, so that each year of data is represented in adjacent columns, and if data isn't present, it's represented as null.

`+------+------+-----------+
| code | year | enquiries |
+------+------+-----------+
|    1 | 2012 |       302 |
|    2 | 2012 |       274 |
|    3 | 2012 |       288 |
|    4 | 2012 |       301 |
|    5 | 2012 |       192 |
|    1 | 2013 |       406 |
|    3 | 2013 |       297 |
|    4 | 2013 |       199 |
|    1 | 2014 |       254 |
|    2 | 2014 |       396 |
|    3 | 2014 |       187 |
|    4 | 2014 |       213 |
|    5 | 2014 |       316 |
|    6 | 2014 |       222 |
+------+------+-----------+`

so that the table above would look like the following:

`+------+------+-----------+------+-----------+------+-----------+
| code | year | enquiries | year | enquiries | year | enquiries |
+------+------+-----------+------+-----------+------+-----------+
|    1 | 2012 | 302       | 2013 | 406       | 2014 | 254       |
|    2 | 2012 | 274       | NULL | NULL      | NULL | NULL      |
|    3 | 2012 | 288       | 2013 | 297       | 2014 | 187       |
|    4 | 2012 | 301       | 2013 | 199       | 2014 | 213       |
|    5 | 2012 | 192       | NULL | NULL      | 2014 | 316       |
|    6 | NULL | NULL      | NULL | NULL      | 2014 | 222       |
+------+------+-----------+------+-----------+------+-----------+`

I think that what I should be looking for is a **full outer join**, but that isn't possible using MySQL.

I managed to get it to join multiple rows together using multiple **LEFT OUTER JOINS**, but this omits any rows where the data isn't present for all 3 years.

Comment: Could you add SQLFiddle ? Thanks

Comment: before table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9be0/1, after table:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df1e2/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the limited number of records you have shown,
you can write a simple pivot solution as below.

But, if the number of years increase, you have to generate this query run time and execute.

```
mysql> select
    ->        code
    ->      , max( case when year=2012 then year end ) as y2012
    ->      , max( case when year=2012 then enquiries end ) as enq_2012
    ->      , max( case when year=2013 then year end ) as y2013
    ->      , max( case when year=2013 then enquiries end ) as enq_2013
    ->      , max( case when year=2014 then year end ) as y2014
    ->      , max( case when year=2014 then enquiries end ) as enq_2014
    ->   from so_20150521.so_q30374911
    ->  group by code
    ->  order by code;
+------+-------+----------+-------+----------+-------+----------+
| code | y2012 | enq_2012 | y2013 | enq_2013 | y2014 | enq_2014 |
+------+-------+----------+-------+----------+-------+----------+
|    1 |  2012 |      302 |  2013 |      406 |  2014 |      254 |
|    2 |  2012 |      274 |  NULL |     NULL |  2014 |      396 |
|    3 |  2012 |      288 |  2013 |      297 |  2014 |      187 |
|    4 |  2012 |      301 |  2013 |      199 |  2014 |      213 |
|    5 |  2012 |      192 |  NULL |     NULL |  2014 |      316 |
|    6 |  NULL |     NULL |  NULL |     NULL |  2014 |      222 |
+------+-------+----------+-------+----------+-------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

**Demo on SQL Fiddle** at *http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a46d/2*

Further simplification can be:

```
mysql> select
    ->        code
    ->      , max( case when year=2012 then enquiries end ) as enq_2012
    ->      , max( case when year=2013 then enquiries end ) as enq_2013
    ->      , max( case when year=2014 then enquiries end ) as enq_2014
    ->   from so_20150521.so_q30374911
    ->  group by code
    ->  order by code;
+------+----------+----------+----------+
| code | enq_2012 | enq_2013 | enq_2014 |
+------+----------+----------+----------+
|    1 |      302 |      406 |      254 |
|    2 |      274 |     NULL |      396 |
|    3 |      288 |      297 |      187 |
|    4 |      301 |      199 |      213 |
|    5 |      192 |     NULL |      316 |
|    6 |     NULL |     NULL |      222 |
+------+----------+----------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was after. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> (SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id) UNION (SELECT * FROM t1
>   RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id)